# What are these objects attached to the cables of this bridge?

Tags: civil-engineering, bridges

Recently, I noticed some strange objects attached to the cables of a bridge (in Münster, Germany):

[image: Bridge]

What are they called and what is their purpose? They don't look like connectors of any kind nor do they seem to provide any support to the cables.

Comment: A better  picture of the bit is needed.

Comment: My first thought was they were acoustical emissions monitors, but I can't find any that look like that or have that kind of placement on cables.

Comment: Wolbecker Road Bridge on the Dortmund-Ems Canal?

Comment: @SolarMike I might take a better picture when I'm near the bridge again.

Comment: @david Exactly, yes.

Comment: I suspected they were initially some form of dampener device.  I did some online hunting and saw that they were not installed when the bridge was initially moved into place.  I also thought they might be some sort of tensioning system for the cables but that would either normally be a turn buckle or some sort of nut system on the ends.  The cable end attachments need a better photo to potentially rule that out.  My last speculation was that they may be some sort of strain gauge system to make the bridge a "smart" bridge and allow engineers to better monitor it performance/health

Answer (score 3):

From a [website of a manufacturer](https://preformed.com/energy/transmission/motion-control/vortx-vibration-damper) of a similarly shaped item, this may be a variation on a Stockbridge Damper:

[image: Stockbridge damper]

Note that the shapes of these types of devices vary from application to application and are likely to be tuned for each specific installation. The "[world of wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockbridge_damper)" provides a summary:

> Stockbridge damper is a tuned mass damper used to suppress
> wind-induced vibrations on slender structures such as overhead power
> lines, long cantilevered signs and cable-stayed bridges. The
> dumbbell-shaped device consists of two masses at the ends of a short
> length of cable or flexible rod, which is clamped at its middle to the
> main cable. The damper is designed to dissipate the energy of
> oscillations in the main cable to an acceptable level.

Comment: Original picture maybe a damper, but does not actually look like a **stockbridge** damper.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a pendulum detuner? Used to control low-frequency vibration coupled to the road bed (rather than high-frequency aolean vibration controlled by stockbridge dampers or spiral vibration dampers).

The bridge is slightly unusual (and slightly modern). Dampers may have been added after testing after original construction.